# Why this python code for insertion into binary search tree not working?

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Why this code for insertion into binary search tree not working?

```
  class BinaryTreeNode:
        def __init__(self,key):
            self.key=key
            self.left=None
            self.right=None

    def insert(root,data):
        if root is None:
            root=BinaryTreeNode(data)
        else:
            if data>root.key:       
                insert(root.right,data)
            else:
                insert(root.left,data)y
```

Comment: Looks like the code in the `else:` block should not be inside of an `else` block

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify what exactly is not working.

Comment: You don't ever assign anything to `root.left` or `root.right`.

Comment: Too many typo errors: remove the `y` at last line, second `defies not properly indented, `insert` needs to have a `self` argument if it is a method and you never assign left and right.

Comment: @MarkMeyer if say root.right is None then it will be assigned the node in the recursive call right?

Comment: @AishvaryKhandelwal, no. Somewhere in the code *you* need to assign it. There needs to be a `root = BinaryTree(value)`  (and/or `root.right`) *somewhere*.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's there in insert functions 3rd line right?

Comment: @AishvaryKhandelwal no. Your instances of `BinaryTree` have properties `left` and `right`. Those properties begin as `None` they never change from none. When you call `insert(root.right,data)` and `root.right` is `None` this becomes `insert(None, data)`. Then you create `BinaryTree` and assign it to the local variable `root`...but that doesn't assign it to the original `root.right` property.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you so much. That cleared my doubt. But why does it work in Java like that? Reference [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-1-search-and-insertion/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the code seems perfectly fine but I have one concern .
In this code , is it **returning** anything ?

```
  class BinaryTreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.key=key
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

def insert(root,data):
    if root is None:
        root=BinaryTreeNode(data)
    else:
        if data>root.key:       
            insert(root.right,data)
        else:
            insert(root.left,data)
    return
```

I added a return in your insert method , maybe it will be able to run now .Due to missing return , your method will keep calling itself , but if it won't return the stack will not close , resulting in your program getting stuck forever .

I have a insert method created as well , maybe you could review and test if you missed out somewhere .

```
def insert(self, val):
    treeNode = Node(val)
    placed = 0
    tmp = self.root
    if not self.root:
        self.root = treeNode
    else:
        while(not placed):
            if val<tmp.info:
                if not tmp.left:
                    tmp.left = treeNode
                    placed = 1
                else:
                    tmp = tmp.left
            else:
                if not tmp.right:
                    tmp.right = treeNode
                    placed = 1
                else:
                    tmp = tmp.right
    return
```